# How would I solve a linear Diophantine congruence in Python?

Tags: python, sympy, number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine

I was given a challenge where the solution involves solving a series of linear modular equations in 14 variables. The following is a selection of these equations:

```
3a + 3b + 3c + 3d + 3e + 3f + 3g + h + i + j + k + l + m + n = 15
7a + 9b + 17c + 11d + 6e + 5f + g = 3
13a + 2b + 9c + 8d + 12f + 13g = 17
5a + 2b + 16c + 12d + 5e + 7f + g = 11
6a + 4b + 9c + 6d + 4e + 9f + 6g + h + 7i + 11j + k + 7l + 11m + n = 8
10a + 15b + 13c + 10d + 15e + 13f + 10g + 12h + 18i + 8j + 12k + 18l + 8m + 12n = 18
9a + 12b + 14c + 4d + 9e + 16f + 3g + 7h + 17i + 11j + 14k + 3l + 18m + n = 15
9a + 12b + 16c + 15d + e + 14f + 6g + 11h + 2i + 9j + 12k + 16l + 15m + n = 14
```

I ended up copying them into [this modular equation solver](https://www.dcode.fr/modular-equation-solver) to get a parameterized solution. However, I want to be able to do this automatically in a Python program, without depending on that website.

Preferably, I should be able to do this with an arbitrary group of (linear) equations, not just these specific ones. Part of my solution for the challenge required me to write a few different equations for different scenarios, and swap them out as needed.

I'm aware that SymPy has [a Diophantine equation solver](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/diophantine.html) that almost does what I want it to do, but in the docs I didn't see a way to get it to enforce a certain modulus (mod 19, mod 23, etc).

Comment: "mod 19, mod 23, etc" -- only modulo some prime? That simplifies matters

Comment: I didn't think about that, haha. But yeah, all the moduli I'm interested in doing this with will be prime.

Comment: have a try with Z3

Comment: Modulo a prime, you're dealing with a field. So you can use Gaussian elimination.

Comment: I'm only aware of being able to use that if you have at least as many equations as variables. What if I don't? I'll only be dealing with 8 equations at a time, in 14 variables.

Comment: You can still use Gaussian elimination for underdetermined systems, but the result encodes solutions in terms of some free variables (which may you want since it describes the entire solution space, or otherwise you can assume that the free variables are zero to make them go away)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word diophantine is misleading here. What you want to do is linear algebra over Z_p meaning the integers modulo a prime p. SymPy can do this if you use DomainMatrix instead of Matrix. This is how to do it in SymPy 1.12:

```
In [1]: from sympy import *

In [2]: from sympy.polys.matrices import DomainMatrix

In [3]: a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n = syms = symbols('a:n')

In [4]: eqs = '''
   ...: 3a + 3b + 3c + 3d + 3e + 3f + 3g + h + i + j + k + l + m + n = 15
   ...: 7a + 9b + 17c + 11d + 6e + 5f + g = 3
   ...: 13a + 2b + 9c + 8d + 12f + 13g = 17
   ...: 5a + 2b + 16c + 12d + 5e + 7f + g = 11
   ...: 6a + 4b + 9c + 6d + 4e + 9f + 6g + h + 7i + 11j + k + 7l + 11m + n = 8
   ...: 10a + 15b + 13c + 10d + 15e + 13f + 10g + 12h + 18i + 8j + 12k + 18l + 8m + 12n = 18
   ...: 9a + 12b + 14c + 4d + 9e + 16f + 3g + 7h + 17i + 11j + 14k + 3l + 18m + n = 15
   ...: 9a + 12b + 16c + 15d + e + 14f + 6g + 11h + 2i + 9j + 12k + 16l + 15m + n = 14
   ...: '''

In [5]: eqs = [parse_expr(eq, transformations='all').subs(I, i) for eq in eqs.strip().splitlines()]

In [6]: M, b = linear_eq_to_matrix(eqs, syms)

In [7]: M
Out[7]: 
⎡3   3   3   3   3   3   3   1   1   1  1   1   1   1 ⎤
⎢                                                     ⎥
⎢7   9   17  11  6   5   1   0   0   0  0   0   0   0 ⎥
⎢                                                     ⎥
⎢13  2   9   8   0   12  13  0   0   0  0   0   0   0 ⎥
⎢                                                     ⎥
⎢5   2   16  12  5   7   1   0   0   0  0   0   0   0 ⎥
⎢                                                     ⎥
⎢6   4   9   6   4   9   6   1   18  0  1   7   11  1 ⎥
⎢                                                     ⎥
⎢10  15  13  10  15  13  10  12  26  0  12  18  8   12⎥
⎢                                                     ⎥
⎢9   12  14  4   9   16  3   7   28  0  14  3   18  1 ⎥
⎢                                                     ⎥
⎣9   12  16  15  1   14  6   11  11  0  12  16  15  1 ⎦

In [8]: b
Out[8]: 
⎡15⎤
⎢  ⎥
⎢3 ⎥
⎢  ⎥
⎢17⎥
⎢  ⎥
⎢11⎥
⎢  ⎥
⎢8 ⎥
⎢  ⎥
⎢18⎥
⎢  ⎥
⎢15⎥
⎢  ⎥
⎣14⎦

In [9]: Z_17 = GF(17, symmetric=False)

In [12]: dM = DomainMatrix.from_Matrix(M).convert_to(Z_17).to_dense()

In [13]: db = DomainMatrix.from_Matrix(b).convert_to(Z_17).to_dense()

In [14]: dM
Out[14]: DomainMatrix([[3 mod 17, 3 mod 17, 3 mod 17, 3 mod 17, 3 mod 17, 3 mod 17, 3 mod 17, 1 mod 17, 1 mod 17, 1 mod 17, 1 mod 17, 1 mod 17, 1 mod 17, 1 mod 17], [7 mod 17, 9 mod 17, 0 mod 17, 11 mod 17, 6 mod 17, 5 mod 17, 1 mod 17, 0 mod 17, 0 mod 17, 0 mod 17, 0 mod 17, 0 mod 17, 0 mod 17, 0 mod 17], [13 mod 17, 2 mod 17, 9 mod 17, 8 mod 17, 0 mod 17, 12 mod 17, 13 mod 17, 0 mod 17, 0 mod 17, 0 mod 17, 0 mod 17, 0 mod 17, 0 mod 17, 0 mod 17], [5 mod 17, 2 mod 17, 16 mod 17, 12 mod 17, 5 mod 17, 7 mod 17, 1 mod 17, 0 mod 17, 0 mod 17, 0 mod 17, 0 mod 17, 0 mod 17, 0 mod 17, 0 mod 17], [6 mod 17, 4 mod 17, 9 mod 17, 6 mod 17, 4 mod 17, 9 mod 17, 6 mod 17, 1 mod 17, 1 mod 17, 0 mod 17, 1 mod 17, 7 mod 17, 11 mod 17, 1 mod 17], [10 mod 17, 15 mod 17, 13 mod 17, 10 mod 17, 15 mod 17, 13 mod 17, 10 mod 17, 12 mod 17, 9 mod 17, 0 mod 17, 12 mod 17, 1 mod 17, 8 mod 17, 12 mod 17], [9 mod 17, 12 mod 17, 14 mod 17, 4 mod 17, 9 mod 17, 16 mod 17, 3 mod 17, 7 mod 17, 11 mod 17, 0 mod 17, 14 mod 17, 3 mod 17, 1 mod 17, 1 mod 17], [9 mod 17, 12 mod 17, 16 mod 17, 15 mod 17, 1 mod 17, 14 mod 17, 6 mod 17, 11 mod 17, 11 mod 17, 0 mod 17, 12 mod 17, 16 mod 17, 15 mod 17, 1 mod 17]], (8, 14), GF(17))

In [15]: db
Out[15]: DomainMatrix([[15 mod 17], [3 mod 17], [0 mod 17], [11 mod 17], [8 mod 17], [1 mod 17], [15 mod 17], [14 mod 17]], (8, 1), GF(17))
```

Now you have dM and db as matrices over Z_17 and you can use whatever matrix operations you want and convert back to Matrix with `to_Matrix`:

```
In [16]: dM.hstack(db).rref()[0].to_Matrix() # RREF of augmented matrix
Out[16]: 
⎡1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  11  11  5   2   2   6   0 ⎤
⎢                                                  ⎥
⎢0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  14  2   11  12  14  13  6 ⎥
⎢                                                  ⎥
⎢0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  3   7   10  11  15  0   5 ⎥
⎢                                                  ⎥
⎢0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  2   2   1   16  16  13  5 ⎥
⎢                                                  ⎥
⎢0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  13  13  16  7   14  0   15⎥
⎢                                                  ⎥
⎢0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  16  10  5   11  15  11  7 ⎥
⎢                                                  ⎥
⎢0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  8   10  6   13  1   0   7 ⎥
⎢                                                  ⎥
⎣0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  4   6   9   6   8   8   16⎦

In [17]: dM.nullspace().to_Matrix() # nullspace of M
Out[17]: 
⎡15  16  1   12  10  11  14  7   11  0   0   0   0   0 ⎤
⎢                                                      ⎥
⎢15  12  8   12  10  9   9   2   0   11  0   0   0   0 ⎥
⎢                                                      ⎥
⎢13  15  9   6   11  13  2   3   0   0   11  0   0   0 ⎥
⎢                                                      ⎥
⎢12  4   15  11  8   15  10  2   0   0   0   11  0   0 ⎥
⎢                                                      ⎥
⎢12  16  5   11  16  5   6   14  0   0   0   0   11  0 ⎥
⎢                                                      ⎥
⎣2   10  0   10  0   15  0   14  0   0   0   0   0   11⎦
```

You can use these to construct your parametric solution:

```
In [30]: p = dM.hstack(db).rref()[0].to_Matrix()[:,-1]

In [31]: p = Matrix.vstack(p, p.zeros(6, 1))

In [32]: p.transpose()
Out[32]: [0  6  5  5  15  7  7  16  0  0  0  0  0  0]

In [33]: (M*p - b).applyfunc(lambda e: e % 17).is_zero_matrix
Out[33]: True

In [34]: N = dM.nullspace().to_Matrix()

In [35]: N = dM.nullspace().transpose().to_Matrix()

In [36]: (M*N).applyfunc(lambda e: e % 17).is_zero_matrix
Out[36]: True
```

The parametric solution is generated from the particular solution and nullspace:

```
In [38]: sol = p + N*Matrix(symbols('alpha:6'))

In [39]: sol
Out[39]: 
⎡  15⋅α₀ + 15⋅α₁ + 13⋅α₂ + 12⋅α₃ + 12⋅α₄ + 2⋅α₅  ⎤
⎢                                                ⎥
⎢16⋅α₀ + 12⋅α₁ + 15⋅α₂ + 4⋅α₃ + 16⋅α₄ + 10⋅α₅ + 6⎥
⎢                                                ⎥
⎢      α₀ + 8⋅α₁ + 9⋅α₂ + 15⋅α₃ + 5⋅α₄ + 5       ⎥
⎢                                                ⎥
⎢12⋅α₀ + 12⋅α₁ + 6⋅α₂ + 11⋅α₃ + 11⋅α₄ + 10⋅α₅ + 5⎥
⎢                                                ⎥
⎢   10⋅α₀ + 10⋅α₁ + 11⋅α₂ + 8⋅α₃ + 16⋅α₄ + 15    ⎥
⎢                                                ⎥
⎢11⋅α₀ + 9⋅α₁ + 13⋅α₂ + 15⋅α₃ + 5⋅α₄ + 15⋅α₅ + 7 ⎥
⎢                                                ⎥
⎢     14⋅α₀ + 9⋅α₁ + 2⋅α₂ + 10⋅α₃ + 6⋅α₄ + 7     ⎥
⎢                                                ⎥
⎢ 7⋅α₀ + 2⋅α₁ + 3⋅α₂ + 2⋅α₃ + 14⋅α₄ + 14⋅α₅ + 16 ⎥
⎢                                                ⎥
⎢                     11⋅α₀                      ⎥
⎢                                                ⎥
⎢                     11⋅α₁                      ⎥
⎢                                                ⎥
⎢                     11⋅α₂                      ⎥
⎢                                                ⎥
⎢                     11⋅α₃                      ⎥
⎢                                                ⎥
⎢                     11⋅α₄                      ⎥
⎢                                                ⎥
⎣                     11⋅α₅                      ⎦
```

Let's check that:

```
In [47]: (M*sol)._rep.convert_to(Z_17[symbols('alpha:6')]).to_Matrix() == b.applyfunc(lambda e: e % 17)
Out[47]: True
```

Comment: Looks like SymPy accidentally recognizes i and j as the complex unit. Should I just skip those letters? Anyway, thank you!

Comment: Never mind about the complex unit problem, I changed `subs(I, i)` to `subs(I, j)` and got it working. I always forget Python uses j instead of i myself, too.